# Why a @Schedule method working with Future's get blocks other @Schedule methods

Tags: spring, spring-3, spring-scheduled

I have this class

```
@Service
@Profile("async")
public class MyServiceImplAsync implements MyService {
..

    @Async
    @Override
    public void printGreetings(String name) {
        //do something and sleep 10 seconds
    }

    @Async
    @Override
    public Future<String> doSomething(String text) {
        //do something and sleep 25 seconds
        return new AsyncResult<String>(text);
    }

}
```

Observe, the two methods use `@Async`

Now, I have the following too:

```
@Component
public class MySchedule {
..
    @Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * ?")
    public void schedule(){
        logger.info("Schedule working at {}", simpleDateFormat.format( new Date() ));
        this.myService.printGreetings("Manolito");
    }

    @Scheduled(cron="*/30 * * * * ?")
    public void scheduleFuture(){
        logger.info("Schedule Future working at {}", simpleDateFormat.format( new Date() ));

        try {
            logger.info("{}", this.myService.doSomething("manolito").get(26, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            logger.error("Error: {}, Class: {}", e.getMessage(), e.getClass());
        }
    }

}
```

The `schedule()` method must be executed each 5 seconds and the `scheduleFuture()` method must be executed each 30 seconds.

I am confused with the following situation:

I can see the `schedule()` method working in peace each 5 seconds, then when the `scheduleFuture()` starts to run, the `scheduleFuture()` method due the Future's **get** method, remains blocked. I am fine with this because it is the expected behaviour according with the [Future API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

I thought:

> Only the `scheduleFuture()` method should be blocked.

**the problem**: I can't understand why `scheduleFuture()` blocks the other `schedule()` method too!. I mean if `scheduleFuture()` is blocked, the `schedule()` remains blocked too!. It can't starts a new cycle or execution. It until `scheduleFuture()` be unblocked again.

Why happens this?

I have **two** `@Scheduled` methods, each one calling **two different** methods annotated with `@Async` of a bean (same situation if the `MyServiceImplAsync` class is `@Scope("prototype")`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the service somewhere else? Because the `@Async` is useless; `@Scheduled` is already going to be invoked in a separate thread by the scheduler so you end up with a forked thread to run a scheduled method whose content forks another thread... Maybe you have a thread pool and all threads are busy?

Comment: "Are you using the service somewhere else?" No, only the **MySchedule** class is using the **MyServiceImplAsync** class and two differents methods. About "Maybe you have a thread pool and all threads are busy?". I don't think so, I am using the default available offered by Spring through the **EnableScheduling** and **EnableAsync** annotations

Comment: BTW by experiment purposes, each **MyServiceImplAsync**'s method has a Thread.sleep(), could be the reason? The Object is being total blocked. But even with that, I have the same blocking effect if the class is declared how **prototype**

Comment: It looks like you are going in a weird trial-run mode here. The code looks rather simple, can you post a project somewhere i can look at? I could copy/paste your code there but I might miss an important piece. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are blocking the single thread that is used to schedule those tasks. From `@EnableScheduling`:

> In all of the above scenarios, a default single-threaded task executor is used. When more control is desired, a @Configuration class may implement SchedulingConfigurer. This allows access to the underlying ScheduledTaskRegistrar instance.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    }
}
```

When you have such issue, a good idea is to configure your logging framework to display the name of the thread. With log4j, you need to add `%t` to your `PatternLayout`

Comment: Thank You very much, I remember have read that sentence from the API, perhaps should be enhanced to indicate about possible or potentials locks if the defaults are used? I did many experiments with the JDK Executor's hierarchy, I know how handle now this. Thank You.

Comment: About "Because you are blocking the single thread that is used to schedule those tasks" what class in the API handles the creation and management of that *Single Thread*?